# I can't get value from xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<info lang="ru" xmlns:x="http://www.yandex.ru/xscript">
    <region id="213" lon="37.617671" lat="55.755768" zoom="10">
        <title>Москва</title>
    </region>
    <traffic lon="37.617671" lat="55.755768" zoom="10"region="213">
        <length>489164.0</length>
        <level>6</level>
        <icon>yellow</icon>
        <timestamp>1365162401</timestamp>
        <time>15:46</time>
        <url>http://maps.yandex.ru/moscow_traffic</url>
        <title>Москва</title>
    </traffic>
</info>
```

And I need to get value from "level"

```
public void GetText(string filename)
    {  
        try
        {
            XDocument xDocument = LoadPage(filename);
            if (xDocument.Root == null) return;
            XElement elem = xDocument.Root.Element("info");
            if (elem != null)
                foreach (var el in elem.Elements("traffic"))
                {
                    Name = el.Element("level").Value;
                };
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

This block of code works good with another xml. It can't find "info", and elem=null. What's wrong with this code. Or how can I get this value in other way. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
XElement elem = xDocument.Root.Element("info");
```

In the XML you've given us, `xDocument.Root` *is* the `info` element. Just change that to:

```
XElement elem = xDocument.Element("info");
```

and that will check that the root element really *is* `info`.

Another alternative would be:

```
foreach (var el in xDocument.Elements("info")
                            .Elements("traffic"))
```

That way you just won't go into the loop body if `Elements(info)` returns an empty collection.

EDIT: If you need it to work on documents where *sometimes* `info` is the root element and sometimes it's not, you might want to use:

```
foreach (var el in xDocument.Descendants("info")
                            .Take(1)
                            .Elements("traffic"))
```

(It's pretty odd to be in that situation though.)

Comment: +1: However, seeing as the code works on another xml, I think it indicates that `info` is the root _some_ of the time, but not all. He should change his XLINQ to reflect this.